# Infinite For Loop that is not paying attention to array-length condition

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

**HTML example**

```
    <html>
       <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130606164012/animalcrossing/images/3/30/Monkey.jpg" width="200px"><br />
       <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02101/monkeys_2101340c.jpg" width="200px"><br />
       <img src="http://www.awallpapersonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Baby-monkeys-pictures-5-419x400.jpg" width="200px"><br />
       <p id="sliderImages"><p>
    </html>
```

**And my Javascript looks like**

```
var monkey = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var paragraph = document.getElementById('thisPar');
paragraph.innerHTML += '<img src="' + monkey[0].src +'" width="200">';
```

Which works perfectly fine.
***HOWEVER WHEN I PUT IT IN A LOOP THAT LOOKS LIKE***

```
var monkey = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var paragraph = document.getElementById('thisPar');
for(var i = 0; i < monkey.length; i++){
    paragraph.innerHTML += '<img src="' + monkey[i].src +'" width="200">';
}
```

It prints an infinite loop of all my monkey pictures. I figure by making the condition dependent on the number of elements in the array "*monkey*" (or the number of img tags on the page), I would be able to print that amount of pictures in the '*thisPar*' paragraph id.

Why is this statement creating an endless loop?

Comment: Every time that you add an element with `innerHTML`, the length of `monkey.length` increases...so it goes on for ever. As suggested by **Notulysses** create a fixed variable for the length that won't be changed with adding to `innerHTML`. Another way to write it is `for (var i = 0, len = monkey.length; i < len; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining the length outside of the For loop, it worked fine.

```
var LENGTH = img.length;
for(var i=0; i < LENGTH; i++){
    monkeyPara.innerHTML += '<img src="' + img[i].src + '" height="42" width="42">';

}
```

Answer (score 5):

[document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) returns a *live* HTMLCollection. Since you are adding more `img` tags, you are extending the collection by one element each cycle through the loop.

If you add a `console.log(monkey.length)` inside your loop, you'll see the problem.

The best solution would be to do this:

```
var monkey = document.querySelectorAll("img");
```

Instead of `getElementsByTagName`. `querySelectorAll` will return a static list.

Here's a fiddle that will show you the length of `monkey.length` on each cycle. I made it a confirm so you can break out by clicking cancel:

http://jsfiddle.net/K266Q/

And here's the fixed version using `querySelectorAll`:

http://jsfiddle.net/K266Q/1/

Copying the length outside the loop also works, but only so long as the items stay in the same order. Here's why simply copying the length can catch you out:

http://jsfiddle.net/K266Q/2/

Notice because in this case I'm inserting the new image at the beginning instead of the end, I end up copying the same image 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

Only works if the new img is inserted after the original set of images : define a variable and assign it to your `monkey` length property outside the loop to make it fixed:

```
var monkeyLength = monkey.length;
for(var i = 0; i < monkeyLength; i++){
   paragraph.innerHTML += '<img src="' + monkey[i].src +'" width="200">';
}
```

Comment: Hah. I actually just tried it and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Notulysses: Only works if the new `img` is inserted *after* the original set of images. The collection is still live.

Answer (score 0):

I think your monkey length grows by one each loop because you are creating a new img tag each loop which adds one to the lenght of monkey